# Build unique & random subset from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, random

I want create a list of subset which should not allow to duplicated item, here my sample code

```
import random
idx = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
n = 3
selected_unique_subset = []
for i in range(n):
    selected_unique_subset.append(set(random.choices(idx, k=int(len(idx) / n))))
print(selected_unique_subset)
```

OUTPUT:
From below list, the subset has duplicated element `2` in the first subset `{2, 5, 7, 12, 19, 25, 28, 29}` 
and `2` in last subset`{2, 7, 15, 17, 21, 24, 26, 27, 30}` , for example

```
[
{2, 5, 7, 12, 19, 25, 28, 29}, 
{8, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 24, 28}, 
{2, 7, 15, 17, 21, 24, 26, 27, 30}
]
```

EXPECTING:

I want to each subset should not contains duplicated item, it should randomly and uniquely .

Could any give me some advice to solve this challenge?

Comment: `id` overwrites a builtin function, FYI. Why not select the sublists, then use `set` on that?

Comment: The question description is unclear even after edit. Why there are only 3 subsets, when you are talking about random subset? And the term 'unique' is also vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set for your initial values.

```
import random
idx = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
       30}
n = 3
k = int(len(idx) / n)
selected_unique_subset = []
for i in range(n):
    subset = set(random.choices(list(idx), k=k))
    idx -= subset
    selected_unique_subset.append(subset)
print(selected_unique_subset)
```

Result:

```
[
  {1, 3, 5, 8, 15, 21, 22, 28}, 
  {7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 23, 27}, 
  {4, 11, 12, 17, 25, 30}
]
```

Comment: why number `2` is missing from any subset?

Comment: also why number `6` is missing from any subset, this should not missing.

Comment: also number `9` is missing too.

Comment: @kn3l Your overall approach is not correct anyway. If I understood you correctly, you want to split the original set into 3 random mixes. But the `random.choises()` function could select one value more than once from the provided collection. That's the reason that your result sets don't have length 10 as expected. So the better approach would be to mix the original list using some randomizer, then split it in equal parts

Comment: Use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle the original list, then just split it into `n` parts

Comment: yes, it like card shuffle, sorry it's my english description is not correct.

Comment: thanks for you figure out `random.shuffle` solved my challenge